# HTML5 video not working

Tags: html, file, video, element

So I added in this element to my html file and when I go into the browser preview, the video box with controls shows up, but I'm not able to press play at all (controls go from white to gray and are not responsive.

```
<video controls>
    <source src="/video/flying_monkey_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The video itself is an mp4 file in the video folder which is a root folder. I'm using chrome.

Comment: The issue is with src="/video/flying_monkey_loop.mp4" , Please change it to either video/flying_money_loop.mp4 or ./video/flying_monkey_loop.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the video folder is subfolder of the folder containing the page you should refer this way :

```
<video controls>
   <source src="./video/flying_monkey_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, but it prompted me to re-check my folder hierarchy and I had skipped over the fact that the video folder was a
 sub-folder of the media folder. It works now! Thanks!